# Preprocessing for using VGG model with VGGFace weights

Tags: keras, vgg-net

What are the preprocessing steps that need to be done to train a finetuned VGG model with pretrained VGGFace weights ?

I am trying to fit an array of images of size 224x224x3 into my finetuned VGG model (freezed last 4 layers of the network), and added some Dense layers on top of it. Training takes a lot of time, but the resultant accuracy I get is very low less than 1% accuracy, and the model never learns at all.

I have used this:

```
vgg16.preprocess_input(img_array)
```

I expect my model to learn atleast if not give a good accuracy. What could I be doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the range of `img_array`? The preprocessing functions will use raw images from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

You can look the exact preprocessing logic up on github. For [VGG16](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/vgg16.py#L20), the general-purpose preprocessing function for imagenet is used. You can find the function [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L157). It is quite verbose because it works both on numpy arrays and on tensors, but what is does is described in the docstring:

```
x: Input Numpy or symbolic tensor, 3D or 4D.
    The preprocessed data is written over the input data
    if the data types are compatible. To avoid this
    behaviour, `numpy.copy(x)` can be used. data_format: Data format of the image tensor/array. mode: One of "caffe", "tf" or "torch".
    - caffe: will convert the images from RGB to BGR,
        then will zero-center each color channel with
        respect to the ImageNet dataset,
        without scaling.
    - tf: will scale pixels between -1 and 1,
        sample-wise.
    - torch: will scale pixels between 0 and 1 and then
        will normalize each channel with respect to the
        ImageNet dataset.
```